# What characters are these? ⿰食㒼, ⿰兌皮

Tags: character-identification

I encountered two characters I cannot find in any database. They are side-by-side compositions of two characters that I do know, but I have not been able to use the information to find something I can copy and paste into text. I tried radical + stroke look up for the characters at https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?cdqrad=184 and https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?cdqrad=107 using the components as a clue and even drawing them directly into a a handwriting keyboard.

The characters below are shown with their probable homophones. (I found it in Yuen Ren Chao's A Project for General Chinese.) So I also tried looking up the Mandarin and Cantonese pronunciations on Unihan database with no luck. They are not found together on Wiktionary's lists of phonetic series either.

---

[image: 瞞 and ⿰食㒼]

瞞 and ⿰食㒼

---

[image: 脫 and ⿰兌皮]

脫 and ⿰兌皮

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 同【满】。

simplified as:

> 

> 表皮破损、脱落

---

The website [zisea](http://zisea.com/) has a function called [两分](http://zisea.com/zslf.htm) where you can easily find these characters.

For the first one you just search 食㒼 as you put in your question:

> [image]

For the second one you need to change 兌 to 兑 and search 兑皮:

> [image]

Comment: Plain as vanilla. I like it!

Answer (score 3):

it’s time to try the 異體字字典, maintained by the ministry of education, taiwan

https://dict.variants.moe.edu.tw/variants/rbt/home.do

the second character is explained as:

> 1.表皮剝落、破損。見《玉篇．皮部》。

> 2.皮壞。見《集韻．入聲．沒韻》。

https://dict.variants.moe.edu.tw/variants/rbt/word_attribute.rbt?quote_code=QzA4MTQ2

have fun :)

Comment: Gosh. I was just on that site and the tab for it still opened! The pronunciation for the character is unexpected from Chao's phonetic description. But more interestingly, as a testament to the rarity of its usage, "" (found on Unihan using the pinyin) shows up as a tofu character on my Android phone---which is extremely ironic given that the font it uses is called NoTo (from **No To**fu). Still no luck with ⿰食㒼 on the site currently. I tried both phonetic look-up and by radical/stroke (食 + 9 or 10 strokes).

Comment: @KevinLi you should use character component lookup, not radical/stroke or phonetic look up (which is inefficient and extremely unreliable even among common characters) . http://www.guoxuedashi.com/zidian/z66595o.html